# Error when attempting to install npm package in a Next.JS project

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Just as the title says. I am tying to install an npm package and am running into an error. The specific package is called [react-mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic). I need to allow the user to record audio and show the wavelength pattern. Here is a picture of my logs and package.json. Hopefully the answer is simple and I am being dumb. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the package is not actively maintained and doesn't support latest versions of react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-mic` depends on React version 16, but you have installed React version 18.

**The first way**

You can try to run the below command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or

```
npm install --force
```

**The second way**

You can downgrade your React version to 16

```
npm uninstall react
npm install react@16.8.0
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Now I just need to work with this old as hell npm package lol. If you know of any other package that is more modern and can let users record audio let me know.

Comment: You're welcome!~ Unfortunately, I don't know any good replacement for this lib. You also can ask lib owners for the upgrade, or you can contribute to their lib :P